# cx_freeze executable not working when I run through cmd in python

Tags: python, cmd, exe, python-3.6, cx-freeze

Hi I have converted my script to exe using cx_freeze but when I am running its not working as expected

My script:`cmd.py`

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


for arg in sys.argv:
    print (arg)
print ("Hello World!")
```

my `setup.py`

having both the scripts in same folder

```
import sys,os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

setup(
    name = "On Dijkstra's Algorithm",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "A Dijkstra's Algorithm help tool.",
    executables = [Executable("cmd.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

A folder named build is created with `cmd.exe` but when I am running the below line in cmd

`cmd one two` nothing is happening, 
Please help

Comment: cmd.exe is the name of Window's cmd. Use another name ...

Comment: I edited the name and ran `cmdl one two`  windoes error message box is popping up

Comment: do i need to run cmdl sys.argv or python cmdl sys.arg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `base` of your Executable as a `Win32GUI` which means that it is supposed to be a GUI only with no console. By doing this, Windows does not make stout and stderr available, and your prints go to the mysterious land of unprinted pages (in other words, they are lost).

You should use the `base="Console"` to be able to see your prints.

Comment: I edited it and ran, but getting this error

`G:\PyScripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>cmdl.exe one two
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'`

Comment: Your script is already executed as a Win32GUI, it's just that the only thing it does is printing and as you cannot see prints (see my first answer), you see nothing happening.

Comment: I edited to `base="Console"` and ran `python setup.py build` again to create a bew build

Comment: And your new error is a known issue of cx_freeze ([see issue](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/311)). From what I can read on github, it has been fixed in latest version 6.0b1 so try updating your version of cx_freeze.

Comment: It is up-to-date :( `G:\PyScripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: cx_Freeze in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

Comment: The fix is in a beta version (6.0b1) so pip will not upgrade to it unless you specify it. Try: `python -m pip install cx_freeze==6.0b1`

Comment: Updated, but now facing different issue `G:\PyScripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>cmdl po po
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "cmdl.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
   
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

Comment: but I already installed numpy, when I am importing numpy in shell, it works great

Comment: I am not supposed to debug your whole script here... I found [this issue](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/205) on github that seems to be your problem. Before asking for help you should search at least a little bit.

Comment: okay, thank you. Mentioned to install python 2.7. why can't we run in 3.6

Comment: The issue has just been raised by someone running python 2.7 but it is the same with python 3.6 apparently.

Comment: now I installed the lastest versioni of cx_freeze from the given link in the github, but still I am getting the same error,


can you check my setup.py once `build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}


base = None



setup(  name = "my prog",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "My application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("new.py", base = "console")])`

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/205.
Someone had the same issue than you, it seems to come from anaconda. They found a quickfix but the issue itself is not fixed in cx_freeze.

Comment: from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable setup( name = "" , version = "0.1" , description = "" , executables = [Executable("")] , )

Comment: while building it is creating too many files and folders, is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: Hi @Marv, thanks for the solution I resolved it but now im getting one more error for sqlite3, I searched my didnt get the result, can you check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194018/receiving-error-while-running-the-program-after-freezing-using-cx-freeze